# Python, How to Print Alphabets to Phonetics

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, input

So I need to create a program that stores the phonetic alphabet in a `list/array`. The program asks the user for input and turns each letter inputted into the phonetic version of each character.

```
e.g Apple = Alpha, Papa, Papa, Lima, Echo.
```

I have no idea how to accomplish this, all that I've managed to come up with is

```
 Phonetics = ["Alpha","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","India","Juliet","Kilo","Lima","Mike","November","Oscar","Papa","Quebec","Romeo","Sierra","Tango","Uniform","Victor","Whiskey","X-Ray","Yankee","Zulu"]
Alphabetics = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
word = (input("Please enter your word: "))
for x in word:
print (x)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach. Creating a dictionary with alphabets as key and phonetics as value.

**For example:**

```
phonetics = ["Alpha","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","India","Juliet","Kilo","Lima","Mike","November","Oscar","Papa","Quebec","Romeo","Sierra","Tango","Uniform","Victor","Whiskey","X-Ray","Yankee","Zulu"]
alphabetics = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
check_value = dict(zip(alphabetics, phonetics)) # {'a': 'Alpha', 'b': 'Bravo', 'c': 'Charlie'......

word = (input("Please enter your word: "))

print(",".join(check_value[l.lower()] for l in word))
# --> Alpha,Papa,Papa,Lima,Echo
```

Answer (score 1):

More Pythonic approach to this

```
phonetics = {
    'a': 'Alpha',
    'b': 'Beta',
    'c': 'Charlie',
    ...
}
word = input("String: ")
for i in word:
    if i.lower() in phonetics.keys():
        print(phonetics[i.lower()])
    else:
        print(i)
```

More about Python dictionary [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/).

Answer (score 0):

Most straight forward using comprehensions,

```
>>> Phonetics = ["Alpha","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","India","Juliet","Kilo","Lima","Mike","November","Oscar","Papa","Quebec","Romeo","Sierra","Tango","Uniform","Victor","Whiskey","X-Ray","Yankee","Zulu"]
>>> inp = input("Please enter your word:")
Please enter your word:alpha
>>> ",".join([j for i in inp for j in Phonetics if j.lower().startswith(i.lower())])'Alpha,Lima,Papa,Hotel,Alpha'
>>>
```

**Answer is:**

```
Alpha,Lima,Papa,Hotel,Alpha
```

Note: for alphabets you can use **module string** instead

```
import string
Alphabets = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Second approach,

**generate Alphabets using Phonetics**

```
>>> Phonetics = ["Alpha","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","India","Juliet","Kilo","Lima","Mike","November","Oscar","Papa","Quebec","Romeo","Sierra","Tango","Uniform","Victor","Whiskey","X-Ray","Yankee","Zulu"]
>>> Alphabets = {i[0].lower(): i for i in Phonetics}
>>> inp = raw_input("Please enter your word:")
Please enter your word:apple
>>> ",".join((Alphabets[i.lower()] for i in inp))
'Alpha,Papa,Papa,Lima,Echo'
>>>
```